# add li to existing ul using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs nested with a ul inside them.

```
<div id="slide1">
    <div class="images">
         <ul>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to add a li dynamically to the ul using jquery.
The selector I am using is..

```
$("#slide1 > div.images ul").append(
```

It does not work. Where am I wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: That's the correct selector. Maybe the problem is with the LI you're trying to add. Show the rest of the code.

Comment: the selector is right, what is the code after append?

Comment: silly mistake on my part..with variable name..works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code should work you just need to define the li

```
var li = $('<li></li>');
li.html('Test!');
$("#slide1 > div.images ul").append(li);
```

Or as PSL pointed out, just: `var li = $('<li>', {'html':'Test!'});`

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EC296/)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to append a li element to the end of your ul:

```
$("#slide1 > div.images ul").append($("<li>my new li</li>"));
```

or if you want to add a li to the beginning of your ul

```
$("#slide1 > div.images ul").prepend($("<li>my new li</li>"));
```